# Forcing cursor to go on text field

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so when my web page loads, the cursor automatically goes to a given text field? (For example, on Google when you load the page, the blinking cursor is already on the search box)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript. e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('search').focus()
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Be careful implementing this functionality. It's very annoying for a user to focus on a field and start typing only to find the caret has been redirected while typing when the page finished loading. I've seen this happen on numerous sites.

I'd suggest using the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute and falling back to a JavaScript solution in browsers which don't support it. The following gets round the above problem by not waiting for the document to load before setting the focus:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" autofocus>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("search");
    if ( !("autofocus" in input) ) {
        input.focus();
    }
</script>
```

More information can be found at diveintohtml.org: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#autofocus

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<body onLoad="document.form1.txtBox1.focus()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML5 is in full force, I believe `autofocus` is well supported. I would take heed to the other answers here, but in my opinion, much easier than JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus>
```